# No me hace scroll en el NavigationDrawer al cambiar la orientación de la pantalla a horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, activity, navigation-drawer

Hacía 4 años que no programaba en Android y estoy intentando pasar un proyecto viejo de API 25 a 29 con las nuevas librerías de AndroidX y intentando creando un nuevo proyecto con la plantilla del NavigationDrawer. Tengo dos problemas en mi aplicación, el primero es que cuando cambio la orientación de la pantalla a horizontal el NavigationDrawer, que tiene varias opciones y no cabe en la pantalla del emulador, cuando arrastro con el ratón hacia abajo no se mueve.
Os paso mi código como lo tengo del archivo que está en res/menu/activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_players"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/icono_jugadores"
        android:title="Jugadores NBA"
        android:icon="@drawable/logojordan" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/galeria_nba"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_stats"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nba_stats"
        android:icon="@drawable/estadisticas_nba"
        android:title="Estadísticas" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_awards"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/premios_nba"
        android:icon="@drawable/mvp"
        android:title="Premios" />
</group>
<item android:title="Valoración">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_rating"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_star"
            android:title="Valorar" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_comments"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
            android:title="Comentar" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Aquí os paso el archivo xml de la actividad principal res/layout/activity_navigation_drawer_jugadores.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contenedor_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.NavigationDrawerJugadoresActivity" >

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y aquí el archivo xml cuando pasas a la orientación horitzontal en el móvil, es este res/layout-land/activity_navigation_drawer_jugadores.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor_jugadores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.jugadores.ListaJugadoresFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_lista_jugadores"
                android:layout_weight="2" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragDetalle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.jugadores.DetalleJugadorFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detalle_jugador"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

También os paso el archivo res/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/nav_players">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_players"
    android:name="com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.jugadores.ListaJugadoresFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_players"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_lista_jugadores" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_nav_players_to_detalleJugadorFragment"
        app:destination="@id/detalleJugadorFragment" />
</fragment>
```

.........

He buscado bastante por internet pero no me ha funcionado nada. He probado de poner un ScrollView situándolo en diferentes partes del código, poner propiedades nuevas al NavigationView, etc... Cabe decir que las librerias que he usado para el NavigationDrawer son nuevas y no hay mucha documentación y si alguien me pudiera ayudar a que funcionase se lo agradecería mucho.

He tenido varios problemes a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación en horitzontal pero hay uno que no entiendo porque pasa, me da el siguiente error:
Process: com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal, PID: 3327
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.adaptadores.AdaptadorJugadores.onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorJugadores.java:47)
at com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.adaptadores.AdaptadorJugadores.onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorJugadores.java:20)

Y mis códigos java son estos:

NavigationDrawerJugadoresActivity.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerJugadoresActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,NavigationView.OnClickListener,ListaJugadoresFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, DetalleJugadorFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,IComunicaFragments {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
ListaJugadoresFragment listaFragment;
DetalleJugadorFragment detalleFragment;
public String getRotation(Context context){
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            return "vertical";
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            return "horizontal";
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            return "vertical inversa";
        default:
            return "horizontal inversa";
    }
}
public static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer_jugadores);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorMenu);

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_players, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_stats,R.id.nav_awards,R.id.nav_comments,R.id.nav_rating)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_drawer_jugadores, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void enviarJugador(JugadorHistorico jugador) {
    detalleFragment = (DetalleJugadorFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragDetalle);
    if(detalleFragment != null && findViewById(R.id.contenedor_fragment) == null) {
        detalleFragment.asignarInformacion(jugador);
    }else {
        detalleFragment = new DetalleJugadorFragment();
        Bundle bundleEnvio = new Bundle();
        bundleEnvio.putSerializable("objeto", jugador);
        detalleFragment.setArguments(bundleEnvio);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, detalleFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

}

ListaJugadoresViewModel.java

```
public class ListaJugadoresViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

public ListaJugadoresViewModel() {
    mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mText.setValue("Lista de jugadores");
}

public LiveData<String> getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

}

IComunicaFragments.java

```
public interface IComunicaFragments {
public void enviarJugador(JugadorHistorico jugador);
```

}

AdaptadorJugadores.java

```
public class AdaptadorJugadores extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorJugadores.JugadoresViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
ArrayList<JugadorHistorico> listaJugadores;
private View.OnClickListener listener;
public AdaptadorJugadores(ArrayList<JugadorHistorico> listaJugadores) {
    this.listaJugadores = listaJugadores;
}

@Override
public JugadoresViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

   /* TextView raya = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.rayaId);

    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) raya.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    raya.setLayoutParams(params);*/

    vista.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new JugadoresViewHolder(vista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(JugadoresViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtNombre.setText(listaJugadores.get(position).getNombreJugador());
    if(Utilidades.portrait && Utilidades.isTablet == false) {
        holder.txtInformacion.setText(listaJugadores.get(position).getInfoJugador());
    }
    holder.foto.setImageResource(listaJugadores.get(position).getImagenJugador());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaJugadores.size();
}
public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(listener != null) {
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
}



public class JugadoresViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtNombre;
    TextView txtInformacion;
    ImageView foto;
    public JugadoresViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
        if(Utilidades.portrait && Utilidades.isTablet == false) {
            txtInformacion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idInfo);
        }
        foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenId);
    }
}
```

}

ListaJugadoresFragment.java

```
public class ListaJugadoresFragment extends Fragment {
ArrayList<JugadorHistorico> listaJugadores;
RecyclerView recyclerJugadores;
Activity activity;
DetalleJugadorFragment detalleFragment;
IComunicaFragments interfaceComunicaFragments;
private ListaJugadoresViewModel listaJugadoresViewModel;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listaJugadoresViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListaJugadoresViewModel.class);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_jugadores, container, false);
    listaJugadores = new ArrayList<JugadorHistorico>();
    recyclerJugadores = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerId);
    recyclerJugadores.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    llenarListaJugadores();
    AdaptadorJugadores adaptador = new AdaptadorJugadores(listaJugadores);
    recyclerJugadores.setAdapter(adaptador);
    adaptador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Selecciona: "+listaJugadores.get(recyclerJugadores.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getNombreJugador(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            interfaceComunicaFragments.enviarJugador(listaJugadores.get(recyclerJugadores.getChildAdapterPosition(view)));
            //Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_nav_players_to_detalleJugadorFragment);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}
public String obtenerCadena(String info) {
    int longitudCadena = info.length();
    String subCadena = info.substring(0,95);
    int ultPos = subCadena.length() -1;
    char ultimaPos;
    char espacio = ' ';
    int posFinal = 95;
    while(info.charAt(ultPos++) != ' ') {
        posFinal = ultPos;
    }
    String cadenaFinal = info.substring(0,posFinal);
    return cadenaFinal;
}
public static boolean esTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
public String getRotation(Context context){
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            return "vertical";
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        default:
            return "horizontal";
    }
}
private void llenarListaJugadores() {
    String infoJordan = "Jugador de baloncesto norteamericano considerado el mejor de la historia de este deporte. Con sus 1,98 metros de altura, Michael Jordan fue un tenaz defensor, un excelente anotador y un pasador rápido e imaginativo";
    String cadenaJordan = obtenerCadena(infoJordan) + " ...";
    String infoChamberlain = "Su juego ofensivo era brillante y eficaz. Jugó dos años en la Universidad de Kansas y al año siguiente entrenó con el equipo de los Harlem Globetrotters, tras lo cual inició su andadura en la NBA como jugador de los Warriors de Filadelfia.";
    String cadenaChamberlain = obtenerCadena(infoChamberlain) + " ...";
    String infoKobe = "Uno de los mejores anotadores en la historia de la NBA. Ganador de tres anillos, vivió a la sombra de la monumental figura de Shaquille O’Neal en Los Ángeles Lakers. Sin el pívot hizo de nuevo campeón a Los Ángeles Lakers, el equipo de su vida";
    String cadenaKobe = obtenerCadena(infoKobe) + " ...";
    String infoLebron = "Es un jugador muy completo, notable, con talento y mucho físico. Ha ganado 3 anillos y imnumerables premios a lo largo de su vigente carrera. Es ya considerado uno de los mejores de la historia y aun le quedan unos años de baloncesto";
    String cadenaLebron = obtenerCadena(infoLebron) + " ...";
    String infoMagic = "Johnson ayudó a que los Lakers se convirtieran en uno de los equipos líderes de la NBA durante la década de los años ochenta, y se le atribuye el aumento del interés de los aficionados por la NBA. Ganó 5 anillos y muchos premios";
    String cadenaMagic = obtenerCadena(infoMagic) + " ...";
    String infoBird = "En 1981 gana su primer Campeonato de la NBA con los Celtics de Boston. Repetiría en 1984 y en 1986. En 1982, le nombran el Jugador Más Valioso del Partido de las Estrellas. En 1992, ganó una medalla olímpica de oro con el Dream Team.";
    String cadenaBird = obtenerCadena(infoBird) + " ...";
    if (esTablet(getContext())) {
        Utilidades.isTablet = true;
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Michael Jordan", cadenaJordan, infoJordan, R.drawable.cara_michael_jordan, R.drawable.fondo_jordan_large));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Wilt Chamberlain", cadenaChamberlain, infoChamberlain, R.drawable.cara_chamberlain, R.drawable.fondo_chamberlain_large));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Kobe Bryant", cadenaKobe, infoKobe, R.drawable.cara_kobe, R.drawable.fondo_kobe_large));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Lebron James", cadenaLebron, infoLebron, R.drawable.cara_lebron, R.drawable.fondo_lebron_large));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Magic Johnson", cadenaMagic, infoMagic, R.drawable.cara_magic, R.drawable.fondo_magic_large));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Larry Bird", cadenaBird, infoBird, R.drawable.cara_bird, R.drawable.fondo_bird_large));
    } else {
        Utilidades.isTablet = false;
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Michael Jordan", cadenaJordan, infoJordan, R.drawable.cara_michael_jordan, R.drawable.fondo_jordan));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Wilt Chamberlain", cadenaChamberlain, infoChamberlain, R.drawable.cara_chamberlain, R.drawable.fondo_chamberlain));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Kobe Bryant", cadenaKobe, infoKobe, R.drawable.cara_kobe, R.drawable.fondo_kobe));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Lebron James", cadenaLebron, infoLebron, R.drawable.cara_lebron, R.drawable.fondo_lebron));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Magic Johnson", cadenaMagic, infoMagic, R.drawable.cara_magic, R.drawable.fondo_magic));
        listaJugadores.add(new JugadorHistorico("Larry Bird", cadenaBird, infoBird, R.drawable.cara_bird, R.drawable.fondo_bird));
    }
}
public ListaJugadoresFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        interfaceComunicaFragments = (IComunicaFragments) this.activity;
    }
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

DetalleJugadorFragment.java

```
public class DetalleJugadorFragment extends Fragment {
TextView textDescripcion;
ImageView imagenDetalle;
public JugadorHistorico objetoJugador;
public DetalleJugadorFragment detalleJugador;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detalle_jugador, container, false);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    imagenDetalle = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenDetalleId);
    textDescripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descripcionId);
    detalleJugador = new DetalleJugadorFragment();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        JugadorHistorico objJugador = (JugadorHistorico) getArguments().getSerializable("objetoJugador");
        if(objJugador != null) {
            asignarInformacion(objJugador);
            setJugador(objJugador);
        }
    }else {
        Bundle objetoJugador = getArguments();
        JugadorHistorico jugador = null;
        if (objetoJugador != null) {
            jugador = (JugadorHistorico) objetoJugador.getSerializable("objeto");
            asignarInformacion(jugador);
            setJugador(jugador);
        }
    }
}
public JugadorHistorico getJugador() {
    return this.objetoJugador;
}
public void setJugador(JugadorHistorico objetoJugador) {
    this.objetoJugador = objetoJugador;
}
public DetalleJugadorFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    JugadorHistorico actualJugador = getJugador();
    outState.putSerializable("objetoJugador", actualJugador);


}

public void asignarInformacion(JugadorHistorico jugador) {
    textDescripcion.setText(jugador.getDetalleJugador());
    imagenDetalle.setImageResource(jugador.getImagenDetalle());
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

En el proyecto he probado de quitar todos los OnFragmentInteractionListener y pasar los datos en un bundle con el método putSerializable y la línia comentada Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_nav_players_to_detalleJugadorFragment); pero tampoco me ha funcionado. De hecho el error que me da es como si no obtuviera la lista listaJugadores pero debugando he visto que sí los captura y tiene como tamaño los seis elementos que he programado. En cambio, me sigue dando el error de null object reference. ¿Alguna idea de porque pasa?.
Para el error del scrolling, he conseguido que me salga la ActionBar creando una nuevo fragment donde cargo otro layout (dentro de este están los fragments de listar jugadores y detalle jugadores para que se vean siguiendo el patrón maestro detalle) y en la activity, dependiendo la orientación de la pantalla, cargo un fragment u otro. Más tarde me di cuenta que este cambio afecta a la manera de funcionar de la app, ja que el patrón maestro detalle no funciona correctamente, cuando clico una opción de la lista en vez de salir la foto y la descripción de ese jugador seleccionado se carga el fragment del detalle sin la lista.
Hay alguna manera de poner código dentro del NavigationDRawer de la actividad principal y que se muestre el ActionBar con el icono hamburguer para poder desplegar el menú?. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

El error

> Process: com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal, PID: 3327
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
> object reference at
> com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.adaptadores.AdaptadorJugadores.onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorJugadores.java:47)
> at
> com.example.jugadoreshistoricosnbafinal.ui.adaptadores.AdaptadorJugadores.onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorJugadores.java:20)

se produce dentro del metodo `onBindViewHolder()`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(JugadoresViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtNombre.setText(listaJugadores.get(position).getNombreJugador());
    if(Utilidades.portrait && Utilidades.isTablet == false) {
        holder.txtInformacion.setText(listaJugadores.get(position).getInfoJugador());
    }
    holder.foto.setImageResource(listaJugadores.get(position).getImagenJugador());
}
```

es debido a que dentro del archivo que carga el Adapter `item_list.xml` no se encuentra el `TextView` con id `idNombre`

Comment: Sí que debería encontrar el archivo, ya que está en el archivo item_list.xml.

Answer (score 0):

El código del item_list.xml es este:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card:cardBackgroundColor="#cce0ef"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagenId"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cara_michael_jordan"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idNombre"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nombre"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Descripcion" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Sí que lo encuentra, en realidad ya he solucionado los problemas sin utilizar la librería AndroidX y de momento me ha funcionado creando una nuevo fragmento que sustituye a ListaJugadoresFragment que llama a un nuevo archivo layout y me carga el diseño de patrón maestro detalle. Todo me va bien, tanto el NavigationDrawer más todo lo que he ido solucionando, excepto que ahora cuando doy al botón atrás, cuando estoy en horizontal me muestra el layout de vertical y se ve mal y cuando estoy en vertical me muestra el layout de horizontal y también se ve mal (todo esto si he cambiado la orientación de la pantalla). Estoy mirando de solucionarlo, seguro que hay alguna solución más óptima que la que he implementado pero por el momento es lo que he hecho.